# Tomcat is serving JNLP Files with the content type "text/html" instead of the JNLP content type

Tags: java, tomcat, java-web-start, jnlp

I've setup a Tomcat for a java web start application. Now I'm offering the `.JNLP` files as download on a static html page (The server is just for internal purposes). But when I click on a file instead of downloading it it opens up and shows the xml code in the browser.

With fiddler I found out that the file will be server with the content type `text/html`instead of `application/x-java-jnlp-file`.

I've already configured the following stuff in my tomcat web.xml:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>debug</param-name>
    <param-value>0</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>listings</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

```
<mime-mapping>
  <extension>jnlp</extension>
  <mime-type>application/x-java-jnlp-file</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Why is Tomcat serving the file with the wrong Content-type?

Comment: You need to use the JNLP Servlet.

Comment: I've added the JNLP Download servlet from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/downloadservletguide.html to the web.xml and restartet the tomcat but still the same problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for my case.

I pasted the `mime-mapping` tags in my global `web.xml` of my tomcat. After restarting the server and clearing the browser cache it was working as expected.

What I've learned: There's no need for an extra servlet to download JNLP files.